# Notification observe are compulsory removed or not?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification, nsnotificationcenter

I have added two times **notification observe** in my app.
My question is : is it compulsory to remove notification observer in my app or not?

If compulsory so, why ? else no, so why?

Comment: removing is the best practice. if you remove mean you will control the battery drain. If you aren't removing the observer it will triggering till the app teminate

Comment: IT depends on the requirement. If your app want to listen to particular notification all the times, then you dont want to remove the observer for that notification. Similarly, you are likely to remove the ones that you don't need at some point of time.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. Can you please explain your question in more detail?

Comment: My question is why??

Comment: You are right @HariKrishnan.P

Comment: @Happynewyear Please check my answer It may help you...

Answer (score 0):

> Unregistering an Observer

Before an object that is observing notifications is deallocated, it must tell the notification center to stop sending it notifications. Otherwise, the next notification gets sent to a nonexistent object and the program crashes. You can send the following message to completely remove an object as an observer of local notifications, regardless of how many objects and notifications for which it registered itself:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

For observers of distributed notifications send:

```
[[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

Use the more specific removeObserver... methods that specify the notification name and observed object to selectively unregister an object for particular notifications.

Ref : [Apple Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Articles/Registering.html)

Hope this will help you to understand remove observer.